# How can i read html file and fetch the data?(not in browser)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to fetch text between tags of html file. a piece of file is below:

```
<div data-status="failed" class="notification is-danger">
                        <h1 class="title is-size-2">0</h1>
                        <p class="title is-size-4">Failed</p>
                    </div>
```

how can i fetch text between h1 and p tag using javascript or node js. i am not talking about inside browser. This html file i have in file local machine and i want to write some static code to read it's content. Please suggest

Comment: Use regex or string methods

Comment: as in? Please suggest. as per your comment it seems easy task but it's not per me. I have thousands line in html file.

Comment: [Do not use regex for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068)

Comment: @AmitParameshwar can you pls help

Comment: @Yash try https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

Comment: There's a perfectly good duplicate question; no need to answer in the comments.